# DefaultTableModel alternative for this

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener, tablemodel

how to add header and data on `DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();` without putting `new DefaultTableModel(inside of this)`?i tried using `dtm.add(data,header);` still isn't working..am i going to use a method?what method it is?

For example:

```
class Table extends JFrame{

    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
    JTable table = new JTable();

    Table(){

        table.setModel(dtm);

        (.....)
    }

    public void thisIsAMethod(){

        Vector<String> header = new Vector<String>();
        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new  Vector<Vector<Object>>();

        (.....) 

        dtm.add(header,data);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the whole table:

```
setDataVector(data , header);
```

For a single column:

```
addColumn(columnName, columnData);
```

Comment: it worked! thanks man, one more thing how can i add row using `rs.next();` or `rs.getString()`